# Date picker for mobile automation

Tags: automation

I am trying to automate android apps using appium. But I am unable to select date from date picker.Can some one help me?

[image]

Comment: Share your code/workaround

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) What have you tried so far?
Please look at [ask]
and [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: add the tags according to the platform or the programming language... and provide proper example as mentioned by others